# Execute Maven command from cron job

Tags: shell, maven, selenium, cron

I have created an automated test suite using Selenium webdriver,Maven & Java.Also I have created a shell script to start web driver and then execute test suite using maven commands. This works well.

But when the same shell script run using a cron job, maven commands are not executed.
I saw some solutions to specify path for maven in the shell script.That also doesn't work for me.

> #!/bin/bash
>
> echo "`/bin/sh /home/loop/bin/startSelenium.sh start`"
>
> cd /home/me/projects/my_test_suite
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/home/me/installs/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin
>
> mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=/src/test/resources/testng.xml -Ptest -Dgroups=group0 >> ~/bin/mvnLogGroup1.txt

What can I do here to run mvn commands through a cron job?

Thanks

Comment: Usually in cron jobs the environment does look like different than under a usual user. I suppose that might be the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by putting the mvn call into a shell script and calling the shell script from cron. The advantage of this way is that you can set up environment variables in the shell script. This here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mvn/bin:/usr/bin
export M2_HOME=/opt/mvn
export M2=/opt/mvn/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/

/opt/mvn/bin/mvn -f /mnt/crawler/versioneye_maven_crawler/pom.xml crawl:clojars
```

I have Maven installed in /opt/mvn. The entry in the crontab looks like this:

```
1 1 * * * /mnt/crawler/clojars.sh >> /mnt/crawler/clojars.txt
```

This works for me on Ubuntu. That's how we crawl [clojars](https://clojars.org/) for [VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/). Hope that helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope running the maven with whole path in your script may help.
`/home/me/installs/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin/mvn  clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=/src/test/resources/testng.xml -Ptest -Dgroups=group0 >> ~/bin/mvnLogGroup1.txt`

Answer (score 0):

From `man crontab`:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by the cron(8) daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are set from the /etc/passwd line of the crontab's owner.  HOME and SHELL may be overridden by settings in the crontab; LOGNAME may not.

PATH (you are using `$PATH`) is not one of those variables! You will need to include things like Java and probably more.

Try this: set your PATH to blank, and then run your script from the command line. This should give you a pretty good idea what else you need to account for in your script.